# Firebase .get function : get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, get, typeerror

anyone knows whats gg on? I followed this online tutorial and actually used this exact same fucntion a year ago. Did updates happens? not sure why I can't run it anymore

this was from a youtube tutorial:

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://capstone-eb408.firebaseio.com/',None)
result=firebase.get("/capstone-eb408/picdetails", '')
print(result)
```

I also tried this and I got the same error ( this was from my prev ears code which ran fine):

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://capstone-eb408.firebaseio.com/',None)
result=firebase.get('picsdetails', 'picname')
print(result)
```

TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

And when I tried this.... they said they needed a string for an argument? but its a string am I right? am confused ehehe:

```
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://capstone-eb408.firebaseio.com/',None)
result=firebase.get('\capstone-eb408\picdetails')
print(result)
```

error: request = urllib.request.Request(json_url+'.json?auth='+self.firebaseToken)

TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Send help hahah :) thanku!!!

Answer (score 0):

FOUND THE ANS!! AND HOPE THE HELPS OTHERS!!!

realize that we need to get credentials and set up that part too now! so here is what to do!

In firebase, go to setting >project settings> service accounts> Firebase admin SDK
you will be able to generate your token! then paste the code you see given to help with authentification into whatever other code you have.
Remember to save the token in a folder and paste the path into the code!!

My code is now this

```
from firebase import firebase
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
''' Database Set Up '''


cred = credentials.Certificate("/Users/Kee Ga Mun/Documents/academics/Term 8/Capstone/firebasekey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication("https://capstone-eb408.firebaseio.com/",None)
data={'Name':'Sembcorp','Number':123543}
result= firebase.post("/capstonert-d9746/Customer",data)
print(result)
```

And we can replace with other get.() etc functions too but this one post data :)